# Outputting PHP to HTML date value issue

Tags: php, html, date, input

When I output a date in PHP to a text box as the value, if there is a space when I set it the element gets all messed up.

Code is 
PHP:

```
$date= date("d-m-Y h:i:s",strtotime($data['Date']));
$type="input"; 
$idname="test";
$idx="1";

 echo  "<".$type." id='".$idname."_". $idx. "' value=".$date." ></input>";
```

the produced HTML looks like

```
input id="test_1" value="01-01-1970" 01:00:00=""
```

If I use

```
 $date= date("d-m-Y|h:i:s",strtotime($data['Date']));
```

Setting the value will work fine. What is going on here?  Why is a quote being added when I ouput the `$date` causing a new parameter to be added to the element?

Comment: `<input>` are self-closing tags, there is no `</input>`. Can we have `var_dump($data['Date']);`?

Comment: What does `echo $date;` return in your first case?

Comment: use missing the single quotes in value attribute `echo  "<".$type." id='".$idname."_". $idx. "' value='".$date."' ></input>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the single quotes around the value, so the space in the date is read as a seperator for a new attribute when the browser tries to fix your mistake.

```
echo  "<".$type." id='".$idname."_". $idx. "' value='".$date."' />";
//                                                  ^         ^
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks adeneo and Tamil Selvan! This was the solution I needed.